# When two coils carrying opposing currents are placed coaxially

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

The current flowing through these coils increases in this case according to the book. But it does not clearly state how.

This is what it says:

> "***When brought closer induced effects should produce repulsion. So currents should increase, so that pole strength increases. Hence repulsion increases***"

The first sentence is agreed. **But how does current increase** ? Its not clear. Can someone explain ?

Comment: And... what book would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember Lenz's Law: as you change the flux through a coil, an e.m.f. is generated that opposes this change.

Therefore, if I have two coils that are a certain distance apart, they will have a certain "shared" flux - flux due to $A$ appearing in coil $B$, for example. Now if we bring $A$ closer to $B$, we change the flux in $B$ due to $A$, and will get a current in $B$ that resists that change. Resisting the change means "create a magnetic field in the other direction". So at coil $B$. there will now be more field due to $B$ (because of the increased current), and more field due to $A$ (because it is closer). And incidentally, the same thing happens in the other direction as well, since $B$ will have the same effect on $A$ and they will in fact reinforce each other.

Answer (score 0):

For eg if certain amount of clockwise current is sent through a coil nd then a second coil is brought closer....as we bring it closer the repulsion increases and the repulsion is of same magnitude as of the experienced current and hence the current is said to be increased